# Conditional SELECT within a Query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with below rows, which i need to join in a complex query

```
COL_1       COL_2     COL_3     COL_4  COL_5
-----       -----     -----     -----   ----
1            A         X         Y
1            *         *         *
.............
.......
```

COL_2, COL_3 and COL_4 can have a specific value or '*' means ALL.

I need to select only one row, if a row found with all the specific values.

```
COL_2 ='A' and COL_3 = 'X' and COL_4 = 'Y' AND COL_1 = '1'
```

If such row not found, a row with below condition should be selected.

```
COL_2 ='*' and COL_3 = '*' and COL_4 = '*' AND COL_1 = '1'
```

If i Use 'OR' for the values, i get both the rows.
Please Help.

Comment: Do you use parenthesis for grouping the conditions?

Comment: You may need an extra condition to exclude the additional rows. it would help to see the query though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complex your situation is, you can check the row's existence:

```
where col2='A' and col3='X' and col4='Y' and col1='1'
or
(
    not exists (select 1 from tbl where col2='A' and col3='X' and col4='Y' and col1='1')
    and col2='*' and col3='*' and col4='*' and col1='1'
)
```

If it's any more complex than this, this technique will get ugly fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. It worked, though compromised with some performance.

Answer (score 0):

Again, depending on how complex this is in real life, something like this may work:

```
select top 1 col2, col3, col4, col1 from
(
    select 1 [priority], col2, col3, col4, col1
    from tbl
    where col2='A' and col3='X' and col4='Y' and col1='1'
    union
    select 2 [priority], col2, col3, col4, col1
    from tbl
    where col2='*' and col3='*' and col4='*' and col1='1'
) x
order by x.priority
```

This will retrieve both possible scenarios, but order them by a given priority (the best one is at the top), then pick the top 1 record.

This technique can be evolved so that you can do more complex things. For example, rather than a fixed `priority` value, you can calculate priority based on how many of the columns actually match vs. how many are stars - maybe start with something like:

```
select top 1 case when col2='A' then 100 when col2='*' then 1 else 0 end
           + case when col3='X' then 100 when col2='*' then 1 else 0 end
           ...etc... [priority]
from tbl
where col2 in ('A','*') and col3 in ('X','*') ...etc...
order by priority desc
```

This retrieves all records that match or have any combination of matches or asterisks, but prioritizes them based on how many real matches are found vs. asterisks (in this case a higher number is a better match).